# Consume RTMP ans distribute via WebSocket

Tags: nginx, websocket, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

I have a Linux PC which streams video (with audio) from a webcam to an **RTMP** server (nginx). The nginx **RTMP** server then converts the video into **HLS** and that HLS stream is shown on the browsers. Everything works good. The only problem is the delay due to the HLS protocol (10-20 seconds depending on the HLS playlist size).

I am looking for an **alternative** to HLS which can run on most of the major browsers. I can not use **WebRTC** due to the lack of audio, I can not use **flash** due to lack of support is mobile browsers. So my question is, is there any way to **consume** the **RTMP** stream, then **distribute** it via **WebSocket** and **play on** modern WebSocket supported **browsers** without any additional plugin? I am using **ffmpeg** to publish the RTMP stream from the Linux PC. If required, the source stream can easily be changed to other live streaming protocol like RTSP. So if there's some other solution which can solve this problem without RTMP, I can go for that too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you able to achieve this then ? Will you please share any tool or open source project or code ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but there's an even simpler solution.  Just stream the data over HTTP.

WebSockets are only needed for bi-directional communication.  You're just sending the video to the client.

Comment: Okay. Got the idea. But I neither know a framework which can convert the RTSP stream to HTTP stream, nor a player which can play that HTTP stream on HTML5. Can you please suggest a framework and a player which can do this?

Comment: FFmpeg can read that stream, do the necessary transcoding and transmuxing to WebM, and output to STDOUT.  From there, any application framework can read from it and stream over HTTP.  I use Node.js for this, but you really could use anything you want.  Make sure your WebM clusters start with keyframes.  As for the player, any browser can read this stream over HTTP.  `<video src="yourstream.webm">`.